# How to do transaction with FlaskSQLAlchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I need to ask the database for data1, then to check this data1 condition, and before anything else changes the state of the data1 in the database, to save new data2. As I know this is done using transactions in SQL and in SQLAlchemy this is done using engine.begin

```
with connection.begin():
        r1 = connection.execute(table1.select())
        connection.execute(table1.insert(), {"col1": 7, "col2": "this is some data"})
```

How can I do the same thing with FlaskSQLAlchemy?

> In my case I will have many servers at the end and If there are two
> sessions, from two users, on different server that run different flask
> application, then how to do this code transaction functionality, if
> the database that both servers use is the same(running only on one
> server)

Comment: flask-sqlalchemy automatically runs each request in a separate session (and so, transaction).  This is done via the SQLAlchemy ORM, whereas your example code uses SQLAlchemy core.

Comment: I am not sure that this is sql transaction. This seems to me just session transaction. Thus same user cannot do more than one thing at time. But if there are few users, then there are few sessions, that might try to change the same peace of the database.  In my case I will have many servers at the end and If there are two sessions, from two users, on different server that run different flask application, then how to do this code transaction functionality, if the database that both servers use is the same(running only on one server)